# Org-mode won't parse dashes correctly when exporting to HTML

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

When exporting an `org-mode` to HTML, orphaned double-dashes formed during `fill-paragraph` don't export correctly as a single, longer dash in the HTML (like all the others do).  Is there a way to fix this?

For example,

```
Lorem -- ipsum doler sit amet --
consectetur adipiscing elit
```

will export as

> Lorem – ipsum doler sit amet -- consectetur adipiscing elit.

instead of

> Lorem – ipsum doler sit amet – consectetur adipiscing elit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fuddling around with it for (more than) a while, I found a workable solution.  `org-mode` (or whatever it uses internally) seems to only parse the sequence `--` (sandwiched by spaces, and not `--`, where there is no trailing space) as an `&ndash;`.  Simply add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'org-export-preprocess-final-hook
          (lambda () (replace-string " --\n" " -- \n")))
```

Comment: I find it both incredibly funny and pretty frustrating that when I google `org-export-preprocess-final-hook`, this is one of the first results to show.  I'm reworking my emacs configuration and cannot find documentation for this hook to properly customize; I believe it has been removed. YMMV.